# Binding variables in dynamic soql

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

I am trying to dyanically attach a WHERE clause to a base query string by following this guide.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm

I am running into an issue where I try to reference a variable and I either get `System.QueryException: expecting a colon, found 'Test'` or `System.QueryException: Variable does not exist: value`
method that generates the WHERE clause

```
private static String constructWhereClause(String baseQuery, Map<String,String> whereMap){
    if(whereMap.size() > 0){
        baseQuery += ' WHERE ';
        Integer i = 0;
        for(String key: whereMap.keySet()){
            String value = whereMap.get(key);
            baseQuery += key + ' = :value'; // or baseQuery += key + ' = ' + value; both are shown as examples in the link
            if(i < whereMap.size() -1){
                baseQuery += ' AND ';
            } 
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return baseQuery;
}
```

Method that executes queries

```
public static List<User> searchUsers(Boolean isActive, String email, String lastName, String role, Id standardProfileId, Id adminProfileId){
    String query = 'SELECT Id, firstName, lastName, email, IsActive, profileId FROM User';
    Map<String, String> whereMap = new Map<String, String>();
        if(lastName != null && lastName.length() > 0){
            whereMap.put('lastName', lastName);
        }
        if(email != null && email.length() > 0){
            whereMap.put('email', email);
        }
        if(isActive != null){
            whereMap.put('isActive', String.valueOf(isActive));
        }
        if(role != null){
            Id profileId;
            if(role == 'Standard'){
                profileId = standardProfileId;
            }else{
                profileId  = adminProfileId;
            }
            whereMap.put('profileId', profileId);
        }
        System.debug('Query Before Where ' + query);
        query = constructWhereClause(query, whereMap);
        System.debug('Query After Where ' + query);
        List<User> results = Database.query(query);
        System.debug('Results: ' + results);
        return results;
}
```

Sample Queries 
`SELECT Id, firstName, lastName, email, IsActive, profileId FROM User WHERE lastName = :value`

`SELECT Id, firstName, lastName, email, IsActive, profileId FROM User WHERE lastName = Test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from Spring'23, this problem now has the native solution:

```
Map<String, Object> acctBinds = new Map<String, Object>{'acctName' => 'Acme Corporation'};
List<Account> accts = 
    Database.queryWithBinds(
        'SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = :acctName', 
        acctBinds, AccessLevel.USER_MODE);
```

new methods are:
`Database.queryWithBinds`, `Database.getQueryLocatorWithBinds`, and `Database.countQueryWithBinds`

References:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_bind_var_soql.htm&type=5&release=242
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.242.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_queryWithBinds

Answer (score 6):

If you are building the Query String dynamically you don't need to bind the variable, just append the value.

I think you would probably have figured this one out if you were to simply debug your query string.

```
<!-- language: lang-apex -->

private static String constructWhereClause(String baseQuery, Map<String,String> whereMap){
    if(whereMap.size() > 0){
        baseQuery += ' WHERE ';
        Integer i = 0;
        for(String key: whereMap.keySet()){
            String value = whereMap.get(key);
            //baseQuery += key + ' = :value'; // or baseQuery += key + ' = ' + value; both are shown as examples in the link
            //Shouldn't work as value is appended as its value
            baseQuery += key + ' = :' + value;
            //This should work
            baseQuery += key + ' = \'' + value + '\'';
            if(i < whereMap.size() -1){
                baseQuery += ' AND ';
            } 
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return baseQuery;
}
```

Comment: Yup it was the quotations. There was a debug statement with the query although I missed the quotations.

Odd they didn't include to mention that in the example code

Comment: Note: Make sure you're using String.escapeSingleQuotes, or you're setting yourself up for injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT Id, firstName, lastName, email, IsActive, profileId FROM User WHERE lastName = Test`

Should be either:

`SELECT Id, firstName, lastName, email, IsActive, profileId FROM User WHERE lastName = :Test`

OR

`SELECT Id, firstName, lastName, email, IsActive, profileId FROM User WHERE lastName = 'Test'`

Note the `Test` has to be either a variable prefixed with a colon, or a string surrounded by quotes.

The value needs to be a variable available within the searchUsers method.

Comment: value is prefixed in the string with a colon.

`baseQuery += key + ' = ' + :value;` gives errors

Comment: @JoeyThomaschaske The value needs to be a variable available within the searchUsers method, or you need to include the actual value within the query.

Answer (score 0):

```apex
public class QueryContact {
    public static Id getContactID(String lastName, String title) {
        try {
            Contact myContact = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE LastName = :lastName AND Title = :title LIMIT 1];
            return myContact.Id;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static Id getContactIDWithBinds(Map<String, Object> bindVars) {
        // do not modify any code above this line
        // implement the logic that will use bindVars to retrieve the contact's ID

        String queryString = 'SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE LastName = :lastName AND Title = :title LIMIT 1';

        try {
            // Ensure that the bind variables contain the necessary keys
            if (bindVars.containsKey('lastName') && bindVars.containsKey('title')) {
                List<Contact> contacts = (List<Contact>)Database.queryWithBinds(queryString, bindVars, AccessLevel.USER_MODE);
                if (contacts != null && !contacts.isEmpty()) {
                    // Assuming you want the first contact's ID if there are matches
                    return contacts[0].Id;
                } else {
                    // Handle the case when no matching contacts are found
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                // Handle the case when required bind variables are not provided
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Handle exceptions, e.g., if the query fails
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 7 years ago someone asked a question, and it got an accepted answer. So what use is your code? If you don't write some words, why would anyone want to bother to look into your code?